# "Failed to parse extension packet in Presence packet" error, causing disconnects, with Smack

Tags: xmpp, smack

I've implemented a chat client that stays online forever and sends messages to different XMPP users. This client is connected to ejabberd server and is implemented in java using Smack.

After exactly 1 minute, the client goes offline and then comes back online in almost 15 seconds. The log that appears on client's console, follows:

```
java.io.EOFException: no more data available - expected end tag </stream:stream> to close start tag <stream:stream> from line 1, parser stopped on END_TAG seen...erd.cloudservicesplatform.biz/cspb2\' id=\'t5f8L-12\' type=\'result\'/>... @1:1264
at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.fillBuf(MXParser.java:3035)
at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.more(MXParser.java:3046)
at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.nextImpl(MXParser.java:1144)
at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.next(MXParser.java:1093)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.parsePackets(PacketReader.java:279)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.access$000(PacketReader.java:44)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader$1.run(PacketReader.java:70)
Failed to parse extension packet in Presence packet.
java.io.EOFException: no more data available - expected end tag </stream:stream> to close start tag <stream:stream> from line 1, parser stopped on END_TAG seen
...<query xmlns=\'jabber:iq:version\'/>\n</iq>... @6:6
at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.fillBuf(MXParser.java:3035)
at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.more(MXParser.java:3046)
at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.nextImpl(MXParser.java:1144)
at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.next(MXParser.java:1093)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.parsePackets(PacketReader.java:279)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.access$000(PacketReader.java:44)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader$1.run(PacketReader.java:70)
Failed to parse extension packet in Presence packet.
java.io.EOFException: no more data available - expected end tag </stream:stream> to close start tag <stream:stream> from line 1, parser stopped on END_TAG seen
...=\'cspbox107@dev-ejabberd.cloudservicesplatform.biz\'/></query></iq>... @6:292
at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.fillBuf(MXParser.java:3035)
at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.more(MXParser.java:3046)
at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.nextImpl(MXParser.java:1144)
at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.next(MXParser.java:1093)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.parsePackets(PacketReader.java:279)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.access$000(PacketReader.java:44)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader$1.run(PacketReader.java:70)
Failed to parse extension packet in Presence packet.
```

Answer (score 0):

Smack until 3.3.0 throw an exception when a malformed presence stanza was received. This behavior was changed with [SMACK-390](http://issues.igniterealtime.org/browse/SMACK-390).

You should:

- update to the latest Smack Version (i.e. 3.4.1 at the time of writing)
- inform the developer of the library/program where the malformed stanza originates from about the bug

**Edit**: After having a close look at the logs and since you didn't mention the used Smack version, it seems also likely that you simply received a malformed stanza which causes the disconnect (This would be a non-recoverable error, even on Smack 3.4.1).